# DataTable NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net

So I have looked through as much reference and previous questions as possible and I can't seem to find the answer, or I may not be understanding it. I have the below code:

```
    public DataSet dsFilter = new DataSet();
    public DataTable dtFilter = new DataTable();

    public frmFilter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cbFilter.SelectedIndex = 0;
        this.dsFilter.Tables.Add(dtFilter);
        this.dsFilter.Tables[0].TableName = "tr_filtered";
    }

    public void SetupFilter()
    {
        lblRecs.Text = this.dsFilter.Tables["tr_filtered"].Rows.Count + "recs";
        LoadListBox("dma_name");
    }

    public void LoadListBox(string colName)
    {
        DataTable dt = this.dsFilter.Tables["tr_filtered"];

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lbFilter.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i != dt.Rows.Count; i++) { lbFilter.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][colName]); }
            object[] items = new object[lbFilter.Items.Count];
            lbFilter.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);
            lbFilter.Items.Clear();
            lbFilter.Items.AddRange(items.AsEnumerable().Distinct().ToArray());
        }
    }
```

However, I am getting a System.NullReferenceException on the below line:

```
     if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
```

From what I have looked at, this error typically only occurs when not initializing, but I thought that I was initializing the DataTable and DataSet correctly. I mean, apparently I'm not and I am hoping somebody can help me or at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: Change the test to be this: `if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! Honestly, I should've caught that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason for this is there is no defined columns for this table hence the Rows became `null` or undefined if you add some columns means you will get and access the rows. Try something like this:

```
dtFilter.TableName = "tr_filtered";
dtFilter.Columns.Add("column1");
dtFilter.Columns.Add("column2");
// add few colums as per the requirements
dsFilter.Tables.Add(dtFilter);
```

Or you can check for existance of rows before accessing them, which is like this:

```
if (dt.Rows != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, I went ahead and updated the test and it worked!